# Pick applicable Excel solvers based on conditional logic (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I am wanting to set up a VBA that will run an appropriate solver based on conditional logic.  For Example: if cell A1 is greater than cell B1 then run Solver1, otherwise run Solver2.  Here is what my Solver1 VBA looks like currently:

```
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AC$79:$AD$79", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="100"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AE$79", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AF$79", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="2"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AG$79", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$X$79", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="10"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AB$79", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="10"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$Y$79:$AA$79", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="100"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$X$79:$AD$79", Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
SolverOk SetCell:="$CQ$4", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$X$79:$AD$79", _
    Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
SolverSolve
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having?   What is the logic you need to apply here ?

Comment: So `If Range("A1").Value > Range("B1").Value Then:  {run solver 1}: Else: {run solver2}: End If``

Comment: Ok, got it.  Now if I want to loop the whole thing for row 80 and following based on cells A2 and B2 and following until I come to a row that doesn't have content in cell A should I create a separate question for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this maybe?

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet, i as Long, rw As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet 'for example

For i = 79 to 90 'for example
    Set rw = ws.Rows(i)
    SolverReset 'clear existing settings
    If Range("A1").Value > Range("B1").Value Then
        'note here Range() is *relative* to `rw`...
        SolverAdd CellRef:=rw.Range("AC1:AD1"), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="100"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=rw.Range("AE1"), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=rw.Range("AF1"), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="2"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=rw.Range("AG1"), Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=rw.Range("X1"), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="10"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=rw.Range("AB1"), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="10"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=rw.Range("Y1:AA1"), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="100"
        SolverAdd CellRef:=rw.Range("X1:AD1"), Relation:=4, FormulaText:="integer"
        SolverOk SetCell:=ws.Range("CQ4"), MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=rw.Range("X1:AD1"), _
        Engine:=3, EngineDesc:="Evolutionary"
        SolverSolve UserFinish:=True 'don't show the results dialog
    Else
        'run a different configuration
    End If
Next i
```